# Visual Studio Full Screen Mode

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Is it possible to remove VS's menu from the full screen mode  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft released [this extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813) that hides the menu bars.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else found a way to do it, but it apperently was buggy:
http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/ide/34228-real-fullscreen-hide-menu.html

Maybe follow the Microsoft link and see if the bug was fixed, or try the code again in the newest versions of VS.

Edit:  Also, this is probably not what you are wanting, but if you didn't know, you can double click an opened file's tab, making it a popout window, then double click it's title bar again and it will fullscreen just that file.  There is no menu, but the bar at the top still exists.

Comment: thanks.  It's too bad there isn't a native VS setting for hiding menus like in SharpDevelope.